# cloud functions v2 memory constraint

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

Am new to GCP and am trying to deploy a function with a slightly higher memory limit(gen 2 cloud functions have support for upto 32GB Memory). The function code works and has been already deployed as cloud function. Now i just want to increase the memory allocated to the function.

P.S I tried to increase the allocated memory using the gcp console, but it fails (no error, just loads endlessly)

P.S I see that gen2 functions are actually deployed as cloud run applications. the `--cpu` is a valid argument to cloud run but not to cloud functions. Alternatively I tried to deploy the function as a cloud run job. However that service is only available in us-central-1 region.

Below is my command:

gcloud functions deploy loadtobigquery --gen2 --runtime python38 --region asia-south1 --trigger-http --memory 1G --timeout 600

However i get the below error.

> ERROR: (gcloud.functions.deploy) INVALID_ARGUMENT: Could not update Cloud Run service loadtobigquery. spec.template.spec.containers[0].resources.limits.memory: Invalid value specified for memory. For 0.166 CPU, memory must be between 128Mi and 512Mi inclusive.
> For more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/memory-limits

I tried to increase the cpu allocation using the `--cpu` flag, but that is not a valid arg for cloud functions.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. It doesn't look like there is a possibility to change this after first creating the function. A (not very elegant) solution could be to delete the current cloud function from the Cloud Functions interface in GCP. Then run the deploy code again

```
gcloud functions deploy loadtobigquery --gen2 --runtime python38 --region asia-south1 --trigger-http --memory 1GiB --timeout 600
```

This worked for me. Note that I have also changed memory to 1GiB instead of 1G. I don't know if this makes any difference though.

NB. It should keep the same URL.

Comment: Yes, I did the same (delete and deploy again). I am not sure if the URL is reliable. It seems to be the same but GCP documentation doesn't mention anything about it. All it says is that URL is currently non-deterministic and does not change on modifications to the function. 
https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/version-comparison

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your args

```
--max-instances=29
```

or add it in the console and it will deploy